# How to autosize element to the next element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu with a logo in the middle.
My logo size is fixed, and every cell has 3 button.

I'm not being able to achieve the result.

** An example :**

```css
  .mainbox {
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#box {
    float: none;
    height: 182px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 109px;
    clear: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
}

#box2 {
    float: none;
    height: 182px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    clear: none;
    width: 349.015625px;
    background-color: rgb(199, 0, 0);
    position: static;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#box1 {
    float: left;
    height: 158px;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 12px;
    clear: none;
    width: 36.182452%;
    background-color: rgb(74, 164, 180);
}

#box3 {
    float: right;
    height: 158px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: -170px;
    clear: none;
    width: 36.18369%;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(78, 180, 74);
}
```

```html
  <div id="mainbox" class="mainbox">
      <div id="box" >
          <div id="box1" >
          </div>
          <div id="box2" >
          </div>
          <div id="box3" >
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**Red box**' size is fixed, and I want the green and blue box to  autoresize in the remaining space on the sides.

How can I make it work ?

**What I mean:**

|||||||||| is middle box

============ are 2 sides boxes with auto size

**Now in different screen widths:**

1x :

============||||||||||============

0.5x :

==========||||||||||==========

0.3x :

=======||||||||||=======

0.2x :

=====||||||||||=====

sorry for bad language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use flexbox? Give this a go:

```css
#box {
    height: 182px;
    background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
    display: flex;
}

#box2 {
    height: 182px;
    width: 349.015625px;
    background-color: rgb(199, 0, 0);
}

#box1 {
    height: 158px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    background-color: rgb(74, 164, 180);
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#box3 {
    height: 158px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    background-color: rgb(78, 180, 74);
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbox" class="mainbox">
    <div id="box" >
        <div id="box1" >
        </div>
        <div id="box2" >
        </div>
        <div id="box3" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Note :** All Answers are good and working , I accepted this answer becuz it's exactly what I need and also it's more simple than other methods. Thanks Everyone :)

Comment: Thanks, glad this helped. Everyone gave really good alternative answers, including @Paulie_D who's answer is very similar, so I'm gonna give an upvote to

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that **provided**  the left and right divs are the same width.

```css
.mainbox {}

#box {
  height: 182px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  display: flex;
}

#box2 {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(199, 0, 0);
}

#box1 {
  margin: 1em;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgb(74, 164, 180);
}

#box3 {
  margin: 1em;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgb(78, 180, 74);
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbox" class="mainbox">
  <div id="box">
    <div id="box1">
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
    </div>
    <div id="box3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have calculated the width of both the boxes by subtracting from the middle box using `width: calc((100% - 350px)/2)`

```css
.mainbox {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#box {
  float: none;
  height: 182px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 109px;
  clear: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
}

#box2 {
  float: none;
  height: 182px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  clear: none;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: rgb(199, 0, 0);
  position: static;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#box1 {
  float: left;
  height: 158px;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-top: 12px;
  clear: none;
  width: calc((100% - 350px)/2);
  background-color: rgb(74, 164, 180);
}

#box3 {
  float: right;
  height: 158px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: -170px;
  clear: none;
  width: calc((100% - 350px)/2);
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0%;
  background-color: rgb(78, 180, 74);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0">
</head>



<body>

  <div id="mainbox" class="mainbox">
    <div id="box">
      <div id="box1">
      </div>
      <div id="box2">
      </div>
      <div id="box3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Awsome Method ! never knew I can use calc in css. All answers are good and working , which one I have to accept ???

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
I tried it with a table

```css
   body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    table {
        width: 100vw;
    }

    tr {
        width: 100vw;
    }

    td {
        width: auto;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .fixedsize {
        width: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0">
</head>


<body>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td class="fixedsize">test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim , Clean , Simple And Nice

Answer (score 0):

Very easy backwards compatibility (floats vs flexbox) is to use 2 floated divs with half size, and an absolute positioned logo in the middle, with negative margins: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luciaannn/3oyg9stp/4/)

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#box {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
#box2 {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  background: red;
}
#box1, 
#box3{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
#box1 {
  padding-right: 120px;
  background: blue;
}
#box3 {
  padding-left: 120px;
  background: green;
}
```